# Example of situation I would like to solve with Machine Learning approach

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I’d like to start studying something about Machine Learning and I decided to start from a practical example/problem that I will explain in a moment, but first I prefer to tell you that:

1. I’m not a programmer (I know something about Python).
2. The game I will describe is an example and I'm actually more interested in understanding how to use a standard approach with ML that is as independent as possible from the game or problem I want to solve (if it is possible).

Let’s start.

The game is described as follow:

1. We have a rectangle LxH (L can be equal to H) and inside it there are two players, A and B (they are two pixels or two little graphical circles).
2. Player A must be moved from starting position (random) to end position and the end position is the rectangle border closer to A such that player B is, at the beginning of the match, between player A and that border.
3. Player B must be moved from starting position (random) to end position and the end position is the position of player A.
4. If player A reach the border of the rectangle (see point 2) without being touched by player B, A wins and B loses.
5. If player B touches player A before A reaches the border of the rectangle (see point 2), A loses and B wins.

A single round/match of the game is defined as a set of movements performed by players A and B from the starting position (random) to the end position (for player A the border described at point 2, for player B the same position of player A). A simulation is defined as a set of matches from which AI can improve itself and learn more and more on how to move better player A and player B in order to obtain the win of A or B in less time.

Well, I’d like to simulate this simple game with a Machine Learning approach in order to:

a. Start the game, at first time, with a full random choice of the next position for players A and B: as result, I’d see a chaotic movements of A and B without any sense.

b. The algorithm, after some matches, should learn something from previous matches in order to move player A mainly to the win border and player B mainly to player A.

c. After a sufficient number of matches, that is after a simulation, I’d like to have a set of rules created by AI (a table of best position values for each situation, for example) that can be used to play the game when player B is moved by user and not by algorithm/computer (only player A is moved by computer with the just created AI from the previous completed simulation).

For example, I can’t think anything that could help me about point b. Maybe I could use a time constraint that is: if after some time player A or player B has not turned away for more than X pixels from its own starting position, then give a bigger weight to the win border direction for player A and a bigger weight to the direction of player A for player B when choosing the new position for both during a single match. But in this case it would be a forcing action added by programmer, not a real improvement of artificial intelligence coming from the simple rules of the game. Or not?

So finally, can you kindly help me understand how to deal with the problem I described (reasoning, mental approaches, python tools, libraries, existing examples code similar to my problem, etc..)?

Thanks for any replies that will help me understand something more about ML starting from a practical problem.

Matteo

**UPDATE 01:**

I post here a python (Python 2.7) script that plots path of player A during a simulation:

```
from __future__ import division
from numpy.random import choice
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import sys   #sys.exit()
import time
import operator
import math



## parameters:
number_of_matches = 100   # for one simulation
max_number_of_movements_in_single_match = 100
directions = [1, 2, 3, 4]   #1=up, 2=left, 3=down, 4=right
weights = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
up_direction_weight = weights[0]
rectangle_width = 8   #x
rectangle_lenght = 12   #y
plot_expiration = 0.01   # seconds



## initialization:
vector_i = []
direction_i = []
half_rectangle_width = rectangle_width/2   #x
half_rectangle_lenght = rectangle_lenght/2   #y



## main code:
for j in range(number_of_matches):   #j=single match

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_aspect(aspect=1)
    ax.set_xlim([0,rectangle_width])
    ax.set_ylim([0,rectangle_lenght])

    plt.text(0, rectangle_lenght+1.5, 'match number: ' + str(j+1), fontsize=10)
    plt.text(0, rectangle_lenght+0.5, 'weights: ' + str(np.around(weights, decimals=2)), fontsize=10)




    x = []
    y = []
    x_init = int(0 + (rectangle_width)*random.random())
    #y_init = int(0 + (half_rectangle_lenght)*random.random())
    y_init = int(0 + (rectangle_lenght)*random.random())


    x.append(x_init)
    y.append(y_init)

    i=0
    while True:   #inside it we calculate the directions for player A in the match j

        plt.scatter(x, y, s=4)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.pause(plot_expiration)



        if y_init == rectangle_lenght:   # if the upper border of rectangle has been reached by player A, calculate new weights array for match j+1, the match j ends
            number_of_up_directions = direction_i.count(1)   # to know how many up directions in match j
            var1 = number_of_up_directions / i
            if var1 > up_direction_weight:
                var2 = 1 - var1
                var3 = var2 / 3
                weights = [var1, var3, var3, var3]
                up_direction_weight = var1
            direction_i = []
            x = []
            y = []
            x_init=half_rectangle_width
            y_init=half_rectangle_lenght
            x.append(x_init)
            y.append(y_init)
            break   # exit from match j to start next match j+1

        if i >= max_number_of_movements_in_single_match:   # if single match takes too time, exit from match j to start next match j+1
            direction_i = []
            x = []
            y = []
            x_init=half_rectangle_width
            y_init=half_rectangle_lenght
            x.append(x_init)
            y.append(y_init)
            break   # exit from match j to start next match j+1

        i=i+1   # next position for player A in the match j


        # weighed random choise/calculation of the direction for player A in the match j
        direction = choice(directions, p=weights)
        direction_i.append(direction)


        # update position of player A in match j, according to geometric constraints
        if direction == 1:
            y_new = y_init + 1
            if y_new >= 0 and y_new <= rectangle_lenght:
                x.append(x_init)
                y.append(y_new)
                y_init = y_new
            else:
                x.append(x_init)
                y.append(y_init)

        if direction == 2:
            x_new = x_init - 1
            if x_new >= 0 and x_new <= rectangle_width:
                x.append(x_new)
                y.append(y_init)
                x_init = x_new
            else:
                x.append(x_init)
                y.append(y_init)

        if direction == 3:
            y_new = y_init - 1
            if y_new >= 0 and y_new <= rectangle_lenght:
                x.append(x_init)
                y.append(y_new)
                y_init = y_new
            else:
                x.append(x_init)
                y.append(y_init)

        if direction == 4:
            x_new = x_init + 1
            if x_new >= 0 and x_new <= rectangle_width:
                x.append(x_new)
                y.append(y_init)
                x_init = x_new
            else:
                x.append(x_init)
                y.append(y_init)


    plt.show(block=False)
    time.sleep(plot_expiration)
    plt.close()


print(weights)
```

The code is far from being optimized and can’t reproduce what I ask in my original question, but it is a first attempt to have something working without any large and complex libraries like TensorFlow, Unity, etc…. It is very simple, it plots the path of player A (see my original question) in several matches and when player A arrives to up border of rectangle, the code updates the direction weight array.

The AI starts with random choice of one direction among 4 possible directions [up, left, down, right].

The best result I can obtain with this type of AI (based on bonus given to up direction if A arrives to up border, and the weight for up direction is the weighted average of all directions in the match), is the weight array [1,0,0,0], that is player A “learns” that it can reach the up border in less time (and with less energy loss) by going along a vertical path. It is quite simple.

**My question is related to player B**: it must “learn” to go where player A is. If B is in the same position of A, B wins. **What do you suggest for a learning AI of player B?** Note that for now I don’t want to give a more smart AI to player A, it is enough for me that it arrives to up border in the least number of movements (vertical path).

For example (examples of answers I expect):

1. player B could have random directions at the beginning but every time it intersect the path of player A, give more weight to direction B->A for every new direction choosen for B.
2. player B could have random directions at the beginning but every time player B moves, give more weight to direction B->A according to distance between A and B.
3. ...

Thank you

Comment: Question is off-topic for SO... maybe you ask at [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi, even if I don't want to develop a game, but I'm only interested in learn something about ML? Note that the simple game I described is an example of a problem that I'd like to solve with a ML approach, I don't want to create that game to play with it, I'd like only to learn how to write an algorithm capable to play that game with a ML approach. thanks

Comment: Still off-topic as too broad; please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that "Questions asking us *to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic", too

Comment: Hi, I understand that my original question may be a little too vague and it is not reflected in the SO rules. I try to reformulate the question by making it simpler:
related to the entire text of the original question, which reasoning/idea would you suggest to address the evolution of AI from random choice of positions of player A and B to a more intelligent choice of the positions in order to achieve the win of A or B? I'm no more interested in recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource... Thank you

Comment: I updated my original question according to SO rules here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the algorithm in a turn based game ( means players take turns to perform moves ) then you can use the Minimax algorithm. It is the best algorithm ever as well as it is simple to interpret and implement 
You can find a implementation of the Minimax algorithm in a TicTacToe game from [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-tic-tac-toe-game-unbeatable-by-using-the-minimax-algorithm-9d690bad4b37)

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggestion, but I ask you if Minimax algorithm uses a training approach (that is it improves itself during execution of several matches) or if it gives always the best solution for the move of player A or B since the first move of the first match of the simulation. Thanks